# code to save setting in registry

Tags: delphi, registry, application-settings

I have a pop-up menu..every time the users log into the system, the pop-up menu will appear
but for the users that don't want this pop-up to appear on their screen, i use checkbox so that the pop-up not appear every time they login.
how i want to save the setting in registry for the users that checked the check box so that
the pop-up menu not appear

Comment: just google "Delphi Registry" and first hit is exactly what you want

Comment: writing to the registry is a pretty bad practice(unless you want to modify OS settings but even in this case it's not really a good idea unless you know what you're doing, based on your question I guess you don't -- no offense!!), I hate applications which messes with the OS registry, please consider using configuration file(s): ini, xml, etc.

Comment: @Dorin: Registry is just there to let the applications write data to it and not reinvent the wheel.. if you don't like it, it is ok... I avid it's use when I expect (hope) and application to be compiled to other platforms (in future delphi releases), but when I know in advance an application is just for windows, I happily use it.

Comment: @jachguate based on zizil's question, I believe he is what some call "a nubie" if that's the case, WE should NOT encourage bad practice, file based configuration is the best approach(after web apps. which usually store info in the user's settings table), HOWEVER everyone is entitled to his own opinion, but I STRONGLY suggest rethinking saving settings/serials/etc. into the registry...

Comment: @Dorin: Persist user selection in a CheckBox between sessions looks like the kind of volatile information which I prefer to store in the registry and for me it is a good practice, I really want to know your arguments to consider that a bad one.

Comment: @Dorin User settings need to go somewhere in the user profile. That's either the registry or a file somewhere under the users profile. Different needs motivate different choices, but using HKCU is perfectly valid choice much of the time.

Comment: ohhh.... today is not a good day for science... anyhu, from my past experience clients tend to copy and paste application folder to USB stick, zip and e-mail, etc. they if you save the settings in the registry, how will they port that? sure you can explain(export settings to a file, later import it and you're done) and he goes: aha, AND WHAT am I paying you for?! maybe I'm getting old or maybe I'm too client oriented OR MAYBE just maybe, I'm NOT SEEING the true potential here?! NOTE: I've used registry in the past...

Comment: @Dorin: On Windows Vista and later your configuration files must go to a writeable directory anyway, storing the application and its settings in the same directory is a no-go today. Using the registry is also perfectly fine, if done correctly.

Comment: @Dorin, your usb stick explanation runs contrary to windows guidelines.  Unless you are writing specifically for USB platforms (U3, PortableApps), do NOT save settings or data to the application folder.

Comment: The definitive tutorial can be found at "[An introduction to working with Windows Registry](http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/tregistry.htm)" Note the introductory "INI vs. Registry"

Answer (score 7):

You can use TRegistry class to Read/Save values from/to registry.
See on Help; There are some samples of use.

For read some like This:

```
 RegNGFS:= TRegistry.Create;
   try
     RegNGFS.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
     if RegNGFS.OpenKey('SOFTWARE\NGFS', FALSE) then begin
       MaxSteps:= RegNGFS.ReadInteger('MaxSteps');
       StopIN:= RegNGFS.ReadInteger('StopIN');
     end;
   finally
     RegNGFS.Free;
   end;
```

For write, some like this:

```
   RegNGFS:= TRegistry.Create;
   try
     RegNGFS.RootKey := HKEY_CURRENT_USER;
     if RegNGFS.OpenKey('SOFTWARE\NGFS', TRUE) then begin
       RegNGFS.ReadInteger('MaxSteps', MaxSteps);
       RegNGFS.ReadInteger('StopIN', StopIN);
     end;
   finally
     RegNGFS.Free;
   end;
```

You an test some methods like WriteBool, ReadBool, ReadString, WriteString,...
Regards

Comment: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE? Is it 1995 again and somebody forgot to tell me?!!  Seriously, user settings go in HKEY_CURRENT_USER for many reasons, not the least of which is that users don't, in general, have write access to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. Also, the write code ought to be writing rather than reading.

Comment: @David Heffernan; Please, it's a very simple sample to see the class TRegistry and the save/write methods. The user must dedice the correct key to save the values.

Comment: @Neftali OK, but it's broken in plenty of ways. The reads will fail if values don't exist. What's more there are no writes in your sample code. It don't compile. Yes I know what you mean, but you might like to edit the code a little. And as for HKLM/HKCU surely for a simple example it would make sense to choose the one that requires no rights and will actually meet the OP's requirements.

Comment: @Neftalí: I'm with David in the way your example suggest to use the HKLM registry root, but this is a bad practice unless you'r application is running with elevated privileges.  To make a better example is matter of just change your example to use HKCU.

Y, es un gusto verte por aquí Neftalí, de verdad es un honor contar con alguien tan brillante en las filas de SO.  Estoy esperando ver el día que haya un sitio como este en español, donde también espero encontrate de cuando en cuando. ;)

Comment: @David Heffernan AND jachguate; You are on right, it's a good example use the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE key for sample code.  I've changed to avoid errors. Thanks. Igualmente es un placer Juan Antonio "verte" por aquí. Al igual que tú, echo en falta sitios como estos entre nuestra comunidad. Un saludo.

Comment: @Neftalí That's better now, but it still doesn't write to the registry. Look at the code again - it only contains read commands!